# Can I slice a string from a certain word in JavaScript, no matter how many characters/words are preceding it?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I have two strings:

```
var string1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

var string2 = "The sluggish, purple fox jumps over a rapid cat.";
```

Is there a way to get all the words from "fox" in both cases?
split() does not work here, because it takes the exact position
of the first letter of fox, "f". But that's the point, what if
the length of words preceding "fox" are different, and the position
of "f" changes? So I want everything after "fox" in every cases,
whether the word starts at position 0, 2, 3, 5, 8 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a substring as an argument to `String.split()` will return an array of the portions of the original string coming before or after that argument, if any.

```js
string1.split('fox') // -> ['The quick brown ', ' jumps over the lazy dog']
string2.split('fox') // -> ['The sluggish, purple ', ' jumps over a rapid cat']
```

(But beware:)

```js
'The foxy fox jumps foxily'.split('fox') // -> ["The ", "y ", " jumps ", "ily"]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good idea, I succeeded to solve the problem by going down this path.



var arr = string1.split('fox');

var arrMod = arr[1].trim();

console.log(arrMod);

Comment: @IllésTóth That works if you're confident that the search string only appears once.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a [`Regular Expression`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
var string1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
var string2 = "The sluggish, purple fox jumps over a rapid cat.";

const regex = /\bfox\b .*/;

console.log(string1.match(regex));
console.log(string2.match(regex));
```

If you don't want to include `fox` in the returned string, you could use this regex instead:

```js
var string1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
var string2 = "The sluggish, purple fox jumps over a rapid cat.";

const regex = /(?<=\bfox\b ).*/;

console.log(string1.match(regex));
console.log(string2.match(regex));
```